# Subversion svn not reverting on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn

I'm having some issues using svn on several ubuntu servers  (both 16.04 and 18.04)

When I run

```
svn revert -R .
```

... I expect it to revert any uncommitted changes. So if I run the command again, there should be no more changes. But no matter how many times I run it, I see the same output, e.g.

```
username@server:/var/www/myapp$ svn revert -R.
Reverted 'views/orders/view.cfm'
Reverted 'views/public/confirmdetails.cfm'
username@server:/var/www/myapp$ svn revert -R.
Reverted 'views/public/confirmdetails.cfm'
Reverted 'views/orders/view.cfm'
username@server:/var/www/myapp$ svn revert -R .
Reverted 'views/orders/view.cfm'
Reverted 'views/public/confirmdetails.cfm'
```

Some sort of permissions thing? I've made the logged in user the owner of the folder, and also tried running as root. When I do that it seems to revert the entire working copy - over and over again.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Did you check status and diff?

Comment: Yes. Both report no changes. Then I run revert and get the output above.